# How to drag and drop while preserving the original android View?

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-view

I'm working on an Android game.

I'm wondering if drag and drop is simply the wrong approach to tackle this.  The effect I'm looking for is to have a button that when the user long-presses, will initiate a drag and drop effect with the drop-shadow being a target.

This custom drag shadow would persist until the user releases the target shadow.  I have the custom shadow working and am responding to drag events.  What I am not sure about is how to make this whole thing work without actually moving the button they are initiating the drag from.

Is it as simple as somehow not passing the originating View (button) to the shadow builder?

EDIT

---

Added definition of touch listener I'm using to initiate the drag.

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        //DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, new TargetDragShadowBuilder(view), view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

I am setting the visibility here, though to be honest I'm frankly trying to follow the tutorial here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Perhaps this is the wrong approach.  I'm basically looking to do the following steps:

1)  Detect a drag event starting with a button

2)  Without altering the button in any way, I want a custom drop shadow of a picture I specify (with a transparency) to appear under the user's finger as they drag across the screen.

Eventually I need to figure out how to make the shadow flash, or linger for a few seconds before disappearing and also to get the location where the user released their finger.  It looks like from the docs I can get that from ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION...?

Comment: What's a "target" and whose shadow are you trying to move?

Comment: I don't really understand the question... in Android, drag operations only "move" the shadow constructed by the `DragShadowBuilder`, the original view is not altered (unless you're doing it explicitly). Exactly what is the problem? If needed, you can provide a totally different shadow by using a custom implementation for `DragShadowBuilder`.

Comment: Let me understand: you want to drag a button having a shadow under it, and when you leave it, the button goes back to its initial position? What do you to do that point where it is released?

Comment: I have a button.  I want to allow the user to drag their finger from that button to elsewhere on the view.  Right now the button is traveling with their finger.  My custom drop shadow is a large red circle.  Once the user releases their finger, the circle and the button are gone.  My desired behavior is for the button to be unaffected entirely and for the red circle to appear when the user drags their finger and to disappear when they let go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that I was setting the view invisible (facepalm) in response to the touch listener. Furthermore my shadow was passing the view to super() making the view come along for the ride. Combined effect was the appearance of the view being dragged away and lost forever. Fixed by removing visibility call and removing the view from super class in customer dropshadowbuilder.

Answer (score 2):

There is an official [API Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) on how to implement Drag and Drop in Android. Unfortunately solution proposed by *bonnyz* does not comply to this guideline - adding a temporary view to indicate a drag operation is somewhat a heavy-weight solution.

Answering your question:

> Is it as simple as somehow not passing the originating View (button) to the shadow builder?

The documentation says:

> View.DragShadowBuilder(View)
>
> This constructor accepts any of your application's View objects. The constructor stores the View object in the View.DragShadowBuilder object, so during the callback you can access it as you construct your drag shadow. It doesn't have to be associated with the View (if any) that the user selected to start the drag operation.

So, the view you pass there is not used to *represent* the shadow. The shadow is what you draw on `Canvas` within `onDrawShadow()` method implementation.

Basically, the shadow is just a graphics that follows the finger while being dropped. It is not a view and does not have to look like any view in the activity. It is arbitrary graphics that provides an idea to the user what is being dragged and dropped.

Comment: Right, but my issue is that the view (the originating button)is actually disappearing when it is being dragged.  I am trying to create a custom drop-shadow while not affecting the originating view (the button).  I'm starting to wonder if the answer is to somehow not make the button have a drag and drop listener, and yet still support the drag and drop-shadow effect.  This doesn't seem like it should be that rare of a scenario

Comment: The button that is being dragged should not register for `setOnDragListener()`. You only set drag listeners for the views to receive the drop. However, in my experiments I could not reproduce your issue - the draggable view never disappears. Do you change its visibility somewhere?

Comment: Added a description for the touch listener I'm using, and yes it is setting the view visibility...something tells me I'm going about this all wrong...

Comment: Issue was that I was setting the view invisible (facepalm) in response to the touch listener.  Furthermore my shadow was passing the view to super() making the view come along for the ride.  Combined effect was the appearance of the view being dragged away and lost forever.  Fixed by removing visibility call and removing the view from super class in customer dropshadowbuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion:

**1)** When user longPress on the button, **get the absolute coordinates** of the button:

```
 int coord[] = new int[2];
 button.getLocationOnScreen(coord);
```

**2)** Create the "*ShadowView*" which need to be shown under the finger while the user drags (as you like)

**3)** Attach the *ShadowView* to the `Window` (leaving others layout inalterated):

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

View shadowView = /..shadow view.../

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
params.x = coord[0]; //add offset if needed 
params.y = coord[1];

windowManager.addView(shadowView, params);
```

**4)** Update `params` using the user **dragging position**.

```
params.x = // drag X - halfsize of the view's width
params.y = // drag Y - halfsize of the view's height
windowManager.updateViewLayout(shadowView, params);
```

**5)** When the user stop dragging, remove the *ShadowView* from the `Window`:

```
windowManager.removeViewImmediate(shadowView);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll experiment with this and let you know how it goes.  If it looks like it's making sense/working I'll Accept and close.

Comment: From looking into this, this appears to be a pretty heavy-handed approach for creating and destroying views that isn't in compliance with the Android Drag and Drop spec.  I'm not sure if that's because my question is driving an atypical scenario, or because of an oversight.  Thanks for the reply and I certainly won't downvote, but I cannot award bounty either.  Thanks again.